# Trying to make a game viewer without changing the location of every object when camera changes

Tags: java

I've build a simple click and drag background for a program I've written which is all good and working. It adds on the distance moved by the mouse while held down. However thinking ahead I'd have to do this for all objects every time I moved the image as I was going to give the objects positions relative to the image and this might cause a few issues with processing power.

What I would like to do is have the background in a set position within the program and move the users view over the image without having to change the position of every object every tick, the problem I'm having is where to start and how to build something like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some idea as to how your space and view-port are defined?

Comment: Currently I just have a JFrame that acts as the view that all objects are rendered onto and I'm just using the individual pixels as units of space currently, does that answer you question?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to tell your program where the objects are supposed to be drawn somehow. 
It sounds like you are currently thinking to draw your frame by looping through your objects and drawing them at their location, and when you move the background, updating the object location.

If that method isn't sitting well with you, you could create a sort of 'map' (2-d array of pixels/locations) that you fill sections in on when you create new objects.  Then when you go to draw your frame, you could scan through some range of positions in your 'map' and draw the objects that you find.  When the background is moved, you could then keep the offset in a single location and use that when determining what range of map values to scan through.

i'm not positive how the processing implications of these two methods compare, i'm sure it depends on the size of your frame, level of detail, and number of objects that you have offscreen at any time.